# Design pattern for writing a list of filters for image uploading using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, file-upload, express

I'm writing a simple image uploader in node.js and express 4.  When the file is posted, the enclosed image will run through a series of filters:

- is this an acceptable MIME type? (jpg, gif, png, tiff)
- does this have a correspondingly acceptable extension?
- is this image less than 2 megabytes?
- has the file been truncated in the upload?

I'm used to doing this sort of thing in synchronous languages, where I would run the object through a series of if's, and return false if something catches.  In javascript, however, the same approach will result in sending multiple headers.

I have gotten around this by nesting the filters in else clauses, but this is quickly becoming very unwieldy.  This seems like a common design pattern, so what is the best way to handle something like this?

app.js:

```
var express     = require('express')
 ,  fs          = require('fs')
 ,  bodyParser  = require('body-parser')
 ,  serveStatic = require('serve-static')
 ,  multer      = require('multer')
 ,  port        = 80
 ;

var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer({ dest: "./images/tmp" }))
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(port);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    res.render("uploader");
});

var uploadConfig = {
    acceptedMimeTypes : [ "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/tiff" ],
    acceptedExtensions : [ "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff" ],
    maxFileSize : 2000000
};

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    var image = req.files.image;
    var removeTempImage = function() {
        fs.unlink('images/tmp/' + image.name)
    };
   // Here is where things become a mess
    if (uploadConfig.acceptedMimeTypes.indexOf(image.mimetype) == -1) {
        removeTempImage();
        res.send({success: false, message: "Incorrect MIME type"});
    } else {
        if (uploadConfig.acceptedExtensions.indexOf(image.extension) == -1) {
            removeTempImage();
            res.send({success: false, message: "Incorrect file extension"});
        } else {
            if (image.size > uploadConfig.maxFileSize) {
                removeTempImage();
                res.send({success: false, message: "File is too large"});
            } else {
                if (image.truncated) {
                    removeTempImage();
                    res.send({success: false, message: "The file was truncated"});      
                } else {
                    // it survived the gauntlet
                    fs.rename('images/tmp/' + image.name, 'public/completeImgs/' + image.name, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            removeTempImage;
                            res.send({success: false, message: err});
                        } else {
                            res.send({success: true, message: "Your image has been saved"});
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


console.log("uploader is listening on port " + port);
```

uploader.jade

```
doctype
html
    head
    body
        h1 Image Uploader
        form(method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data")
            input(type="file" name="image")
            input(type="submit")
        h1 !{test}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Promise library such as [BlueBird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird):

```
Promise.resolve(image)
    .then(function(image) {
        if (uploadConfig.acceptedMimeTypes.indexOf(image.mimetype) == -1) {
            throw "Incorrect MIME type";
        }
        return image;
    })
    .then(function(image) {
        if (image.size > uploadConfig.maxFileSize) {
            throw "File is too large";
        }
        return image;
    })
    .then(function(image) {
        if (image.truncated) {
            throw "The file was truncated";
        }
        return image;
    })
    .then(function(image) {
        return fs.renameAsync('images/tmp/' + image.name, 'public/completeImgs/' + image.name)
    })
    .then(function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    })
    .then(function() {
        res.send({success: true, message: "Your image has been saved"});
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        removeTempImage();
        res.send({success: false, message: err});
    });
```

Comment: @prc322 had a good point, that my example doesn't need a synchronous pattern, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all your checks are sync. Just go with something like this:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next)
{
    var image = req.files.image;
    var removeTempImage = function ()
    {
        fs.unlink('images/tmp/' + image.name)
    };

    // Here is where things become a mess
    if (uploadConfig.acceptedMimeTypes.indexOf(image.mimetype) == -1)
    {
        removeTempImage();
        res.send({ success: false, message: "Incorrect MIME type" });
        return;
    }

    if (uploadConfig.acceptedExtensions.indexOf(image.extension) == -1)
    {
        removeTempImage();
        res.send({ success: false, message: "Incorrect file extension" });
        return;
    }

    if (image.size > uploadConfig.maxFileSize)
    {
        removeTempImage();
        res.send({ success: false, message: "File is too large" });
        return;
    }

    if (image.truncated)
    {
        removeTempImage();
        res.send({ success: false, message: "The file was truncated" });
        return;
    }

    // it survived the gauntlet
    fs.rename('images/tmp/' + image.name, 'public/completeImgs/' + image.name, function (err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            removeTempImage;
            res.send({ success: false, message: err });
        } else
        {
            res.send({ success: true, message: "Your image has been saved" });
        }
    });
});
```

Besides, most of nodes OOTB async functions [also available as sync versions](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath).

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to do it, and requires the least processing power, so it's the best for my specific problem (which was actually a poor example of something that needs a synchronous design pattern).  I'm going to implement this in my code, but I'm marking @MattDavey as correct because he gave me the design pattern for synchronous checks.

Comment: I'm okay with the 2nd place if the price is an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used multer yet myself, but if you look at the multer page it has a number of options, one of which will allow you to eliminate the size check at least. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer.  Also, you don't have to do anything asynchronous here.  By the time your post function is called the multer object is already filled out and the file is waiting for you.

But what about something like this:

```
var error_messages = '';
if (uploadConfig.acceptedMimeTypes.indexOf(image.mimetype) == -1) {
    error_messages = "Incorrect MIME type ";
}
if (uploadConfig.acceptedExtensions.indexOf(image.extension) == -1) {
    error_messages += "Incorrect file extension ";
}
if (image.size > uploadConfig.maxFileSize) {
    error_messages +=  "File is too large ");
}
if (image.truncated) {
    error_messages +=  "The file was truncated ";      
}

if(error_messages === ''){
    fs.rename('images/tmp/' + image.name, 'public/completeImgs/' + image.name, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            removeTempImage;
            res.send({success: false, message: err});
        }
        else {
            res.send({success: true, message: "Your image has been saved"});
        }
    });
}
else {
    res.send({success: false, message: error_messages});
}
```

Admittedly it's hokey to just concatenate the error messages like that.  You could put them in an array and pass the array to the view or something.

Comment: I used to do this a lot in PHP, but I'm not a fan of it anymore.  It's more annoying to write, runs things through a longer process, and gives users the level of feedback and detail that should be provided by their client validation.